# Make a .bin file human readable in python

Tags: python, binaryfiles, decoder

I am getting a .bin file from a C++ program. File has content similar to one below.
 `12 MyName here 456`

How can I read this file in python and make the content human readable?

I am trying with the program below. But it just gives me a byte string.

```
binary_file_path = "binary_file.bin"
with open(binary_file_path, "rb") as b_file:
   binary_data = b_file.read()

print(binary_data)
```

I just want to display contents of .bin file in human readable format.

Comment: You say that the file contains something like "12 MyName here 456". Then you should be able to open it in text mode.

Comment: If it only contains ascii characters like `12 MyName here 456` you could juste use `'r'` flag to open it (instead of your `'rb'`)

Comment: tried with just the "r" flag, getting following output

   @LSy                 º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­ºîþ

Comment: In that case the file doesn't contain just "12 MyName here 456".

Comment: What should I do now? @Matthias

Comment: Ask the person who gave you the file what format it is in. It could be a text file with an unusual encoding. It could also be a binary file where you need some complex code to interpret the data.